# Getting the cell values for a selected row

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm trying to work out how to select the data (cell values) from a row. The docs don't seem to be that clear and the examples for adding hooks seems to be somewhat overwhelming.

https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/Hooks.html

This what I've tried.

```js
var data = [
        ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
        ["2014", 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ["2015", 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ["2016", 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ];

    var container = document.getElementById('example');
    var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
        data: data,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        contextMenu: true
    });
    
    //This is where I think I should add something like this but this is where I'm lost.
    
    hot.addHook('getCell');
```

```html
<link href="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="./node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="./node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css">


</head>
<body>

<div id="example"></div>
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. From reading the docs looks like you need to give the hook a callback. Since you want to get the row when a cell is clicked the event you want to register is [`afterSelection`](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/Hooks.html#event:afterSelection).
This callback is fired after one or more cells are selected (e.g. during mouse move), when that happens you get access to the parameters of the callback. Then you can just use the Handsontable core api to pull the [cell](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/Core.html#getDataAtCell)/[row](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/Core.html#getDataAtRow)/[col](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/Core.html#getDataAtCol)/etc data

```js
var data = [
  ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
  ["2014", 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ["2015", 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ["2016", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

var container = document.getElementById('example');
var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: data,
  minSpareRows: 1,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  contextMenu: true
});


// create a hook with an event from Handstable core events 
hot.addHook('afterSelection', function(row,column){
  const selectedCell = hot.getDataAtCell(row,column); 
  const selectedCol = hot.getDataAtCol(column);
  const selectedRow = hot.getDataAtRow(row);
  
  console.log(`selected cell [${row}][${column}] with value [${selectedCell}]`)
  console.log(`column values: ${JSON.stringify(selectedCol)}`);
  console.log(`row values: ${JSON.stringify(selectedRow)}`)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <script src="./node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="./node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css">


</head>

<body>

  <div id="example"></div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Arh thankyou! Should `getCell` fire each time a row is selected?

Comment: @user1513388 no it doesn't thats an event hook there's actually tons of them in the docs and you would use them in the same way. The one I wrote in the example is an arbitrary call to get a row when you call `getCell`; I assumed that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Almost what I need. Essentially,I’m tryout to grab the row data when the row is selected so that I can pass it to a HighCharts chart.

Comment: @user1513388 I just updated the example with an event instead of the custom hook. That should be what you're looking for and you can use it the same way with all the other events.

Comment: Perfect almost exactly what I need. How would I get all of the cells in the row not just the first cell in the row?

Comment: @user1513388 you can use the row/col to get the data you need with core's api. I updated the answer with links to the sections I used.